# MVC Modelbinding jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a Problem with my Modelbinding and i cant figure it out why it wouldnt work.
Heres the Controller:

```
    public class ItemListController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string name)
    {           
        return View();
    }

}
```

this is the javascript

```
  var myObject = JSON.stringify("{Name: 'Test'}");

    var dataobject = 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ItemList/Create",
        data: myObject,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {
        alert(data);
    }

    function errorFunc() {
        alert('error');
        console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: myData }));
    }
});
```

If tried nearly everything ive read. Can someone please let me know why binding is not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it without `JSON.stringify` :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ItemList/Create",
    data: {Name: 'Test'},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});

function successFunc(data, status) {
    alert(data);
}

function errorFunc() {
    alert('error');
    console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: myData }));
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not... also tried {'Name' : 'test'} {Name:test} and so on

Comment: you need to remove dataType: "json" bacause the action return a view(html) not json

Comment: when i look at the networktraffic there is a payload Name:"Test" but the string in the conrtoller method keeps null

Comment: try to remove contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: when you use it the action bind only objects